# jQuery lightbox Gallery

Tags: jquery, lightbox, gallery

Does a jQuery plug-in exist with standard lightbox functionality?

In the "lightbox" window I'd like to show the current image and the rest as thumbnails somewhere (left, bottom, etc.) in the same "lightbox" window.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) - A light-weight, customizable lightbox plugin for jQuery  jQuery 1.3.2+ in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.

Comment: yea this one will do. thanx :)

Answer (score 3):

I've found [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) to be very easy and very flexible to use.

Comment: FYI to all,  thickbox is not longer maintained

Answer (score 3):

Another option is [slimbox 2](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2). It is a visual clone of [lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) using JQuery with a few minor visual enhancements, and an internal redesign.

> It was designed to be very small,
>   efficient, standards-friendly, fully
>   customizable, more convenient and 100%
>   compatible with the original Lightbox
>   2.

I've used Slimbox personally, and can firmly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that this thread wasn't updated for awhile. Check the [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) that was very recently released.