# pop up lightbox gallery

Tags: lightbox, gallery

anyone know how to make the gallery just like the autotrader when you click on the car image?
It will popup a lightbox when you click on image and have a galleria like gallery.

www.autotrader.com

Answer (score 0):

There are many javascript libraries available. Check out this list of jquery [lightbox plugins](http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts). Also you can look at this jquery plugin [mb.gallery](http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/mb.gallery/gallery.html). There is another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043978/jquery-lightbox-gallery) running on stackoverflow which has a lot of answers.